# Disk Utility 15.0 fails at formatting a brand new hard drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, utilities

I just got a WD My Passport 4Tb external hard drive (USB) and need to format it before use.

I've done this successfully many times before Disk Utility version 15.0 (earlier OSes than El Capitan), but after trying twice today, the operation failed each time.

### First step:

[image]
*The My Passport disk is the one on the bottom.*

### Second step:

[image]

I prefer to keep this computer on El Capitan for compatibility-related reasons.

### Edit:

Following [Phoenix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/111534/phoenix)'s suggestion, I unearthed my old Powerbook G4 from 2004  running OS X 10.5.8 and Disk Utility 11 to try and format the drive. It worked like a charm (I did it twice to be sure):

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Which solves the problem, but doesn't answer the question...*

### Can I format this drive on El Capitan's Disk Utility?

Comment: Have you tried to format this particular drive with a different computer or operating system (if you have) to see if you run into the same problem? You can also run `diskutil` from Terminal and see if it works there or provides you with a more detailed error message. Running `diskutil` without a mode will give you help on available modes. Running it with a valid mode will provide you help on how to use that mode (e.g. additional parameters). Good advice is to run `diskutil list` to get the list of drives and partitions before actually committing any format/erase command.

Comment: @Phoenix see my edit ;)

Comment: Perfect. It worked. It was indeed meant to narrow down the issue, but not a real answer, hence I made a comment. ;-) To try again, you could reformat the drive using free space as partition, which would remove any partition again. While I do not know if such drives come entirely unformatted or have a MBR or GPT structure already done, reformatting the drive as suggested would at least leave one of the structures in place (whichever you choose during that operation).